# Why this li:last-child is not working for my unordered list?

Tags: html, css

```css
.navbar-nav{
          margin: 0 auto;
          display: table;
          table-layout: fixed;
          float:none;
      }

      .navbar-collapse ul li a {
        border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
        padding: 0 10px;
        margin-top:15px;
      }
       .navbar-collapse ul li:last-child {
        border:none;
      }
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
            <li><a href="#">MANUALS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SPARE PART</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WHERE TO BUY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EDIT BOOK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ADMIN</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

I need git rid off my right border of last li item.I set border:none for li:last-child but not working.

Anything I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your styling is you should be targeting the last `li` of the `last-child` first then style the `a`

add the following css for the fix

**CSS**

```
.navbar-collapse ul li:last-child a {
    border-right: medium none;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vb7gbny/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You should target the `li` element with the `last-child` and then apply the rule to the `a` tag.

```
  .navbar-collapse ul li:last-child a {
      border:none;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.navbar-nav{
          margin: 0 auto;
          display: table;
          table-layout: fixed;
          float:none;
      }

      .navbar-collapse ul li a {
        border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
        padding: 0 10px;
        margin-top:15px;
      }
       .navbar-collapse ul li:last-child a{
        border:none;
      }
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
            <li><a href="#">MANUALS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SPARE PART</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WHERE TO BUY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EDIT BOOK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ADMIN</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Apply style on `a` inside `li:last-child`

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
.navbar-collapse ul li:last-child a{
    border-right:none;
}
```

### here is the running example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .navbar-nav{
              margin: 0 auto;
              display: table;
              table-layout: fixed;
              float:none;
          }

          .navbar-collapse ul li a {
            border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
            padding: 0 10px;
            margin-top:15px;
          }
           .navbar-collapse ul li:last-child a{
       
            border-right:none;
          }

</style>

  



</head>
<body>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
            <li><a href="#">MANUALS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SPARE PART</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WHERE TO BUY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EDIT BOOK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ADMIN</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```